# Building a JSON request reply server on Google drive

Tags: json, google-drive-api, hosting, web-deployment, web-hosting

[This query is online hosting related, and not on Android dev part]

I am developing an Android app for which I need to get a JSON string from the Internet when the app starts. This JSON string contains small chunks of data and therefore will not be more than few MBs. I want to host this JSON data on the server.

I am not much into web development but I did read about how to host websites. My problem is, unlike hosting websites, I simply want to create a request-response server which responds with a JSON string when requested from Android app. Can I create a server which does this and host it on google drive or dropbox? If yes, how?

I tried Googling but didn't help much. I do not need explanation, if I get some guidance I'll search the rest. TIA

Answer (score 1):

you can try Gooble fire base

https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

check spark package where u can host and store

Comment: Great thing! Unfortunately it only supports static hosting.